# What is the best way to set hot water pastry?

Tags: baking, food-safety, pastry

Some hot water pie recipes require the pastry to be moulded into shape and left to dry out and set overnight or up to 24 hours before filling and baking (e.g. Scotch pies).

Is it best to leave the pastry open to the air or place it in the fridge? Will covering the pastry (e.g. with clingfilm etc.) hinder the drying out process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The refrigerator would be safer and effective for drying and setting the shape.

The hydrated cooked starch would support pathogen growth. Dehydration occurs more slowly, but still occurs under refrigeration temperature. The cooling would also solidify the milk fat and partially retrograde the starch faster than at room temperature, so it may be set solidly enough to work with without needing an overnight rest.

Comment: The inside of a refrigerator is very dry so even though it's cold it a good place to do this.

Comment: does the rest of the ingredients not inhibit pathogen growth? it would be strange to me if recipes _required_ the cook to do something not safe